# DataBase datetime null handle

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql, database

i have the following code:

```
var distinctRows = 
      (from row in ds.GetTable(this.TagShortName).AsEnumerable()
         select new Audit    
          {
             ID =row.Field<long>("ID"),
             UpdatedBy =string.Format("{0} {1}", 
                                      row.Field<string>("UpdatedByFirstName"),
                                      row.Field<string>("UpdatedByLastName")),
             UpdatedOn = ow.Field<DateTime>("UpdatedOn")
          }).Distinct(new AuditComparer());
```

when i have null value in UpdateOn field it throw exception on:

```
UpdatedOn =row.Field<DateTime>("UpdatedOn")
```

exception: Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.DateTime'. Please use a nullable type.

how to handle this?

Comment: Well what is `UpdatedOn` datatype you will need that to be `DateTime?`

Answer (score 1):

Make `UpdatedOn` nullable or

```
UpdatedOn = row.Field<DateTime?>("UpdatedOn")?? DateTime.MinValue
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Nullable<DateTime>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) or `DateTime?`

```
UpdatedOn = row.Field<DateTime?>("UpdatedOn")
```

Comment: row.Field<DateTime?>("UpdatedOn") not working i already try this. how to use Nullable<DateTime> in my case?

Comment: @NomiAli, `Nullable<DateTime>` is same as `DateTime?`, the later is just syntactic suger, you need to make sure that your `UpdatedOn` is also defined as `DateTime?`, or you need to check it against `null` and then assign `UpdatedOn` some default value.

Comment: Make sure UpdatedOn defined Nullable in entity data model.

Comment: thanks man! actually my UpdatedOn was not nullable in entity. Thanks for the answers.